# After Inapp purshase touch action disabled in corona sdk?

Tags: coronasdk

In my application i used in-app purchase.purchase and restore option doing well on my device.once in-app purchase or restore finished i set to remove lock image.but touch action not be called.in transaction callback function

```
 if event.transaction.state == "purchased" then
 db:exec("UPDATE inapproom SET product=1 WHERE id=1")
 native.setActivityIndicator( false );
 db:close()
 store.finishTransaction( event.transaction )
 sqlite3=nil;

            lock1.alpha=0; 
            lock2.alpha=0; 
            lock3.alpha=0; 
            lock4.alpha=0; 
            lock5.alpha=0;     
            lock6.alpha=0;
```

but touch action not calling.when i move to other page and return back it work properly.

Comment: I think, you are `updating` the database when you purchase the item. At the same time, you have to `add EventListeners` for your buttons either directly, or by `reading` from data base, and set the `touch listeners`..... :)